# Flutter async method keeps running even after the corresponding widget is removed

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a list of image paths and I am using the `List.generate` method to display images and a cross icon to remove image from list. Upload method is called on each image and when I remove the image from the list the method still keeps running until the image is uploaded. The behavior I am expecting is when I remove the image from the list the method should also stop running. I am using a future builder to display the circular progress bar and error icons while uploading an image.

What should I be doing to make sure the future method associated to the current widget also stops when I remove the widget from the list?

This is the code where I am creating a list

```
           List.generate(
            files.length,
            (index) {
              var image = files[index];             
              return Container(
                height: itemSize,
                width: itemSize,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                       getImagePreview(image, itemSize)                          
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        uploadHandler(image, field),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () => removeFileAtIndex(index, field),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.7),
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              height: 22,
                              width: 22,
                              child: Icon(Icons.close, size: 18, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          )
```

This is Upload Handler method.

```
Widget uploadHandler(file, field) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: upload(file),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.data.statusCode == 201) {            
            return doneUpload();
          } else {
            logger.d(snapshot.error);
            return error();
          }
        } else {
          return uploading();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle of the widget isn't attached to the async functions invoked by the widget.

You can check the [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) variable to check if the widget still mounted from your async function.